# Perform click on one div after the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you understand my problem.

At the moment I have a JS-function that choses randomly a div of a specific Html-Class.

Now i would like to rewrite the function that it picks one div after the other, just like they are ordered in the HTML-content.

How can I do this?

For information: the random selection is made with jquery and looks like this:

```
function pickrandom() {
   var elems = $(".classname");
   if (elems.length) {
       var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
       console.log(keep);
       $(elems[keep]).click();
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: a fiddle/code would be great to make your problem more clearly

Comment: Start by rewriting the function.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you chose a random div (let's say the third one) and you want to perform clicks on div 3 to ... (amount of divs on the page)?

Comment: @Jorrex I should work like this: The user clicks on one div (let's say like you did the third one). After a specific time the function should perform a click on the fourth one...

Comment: if you want to auto click by doing this `$(elems[keep]).click();` this is bad method, you should try  `$(elems[keep]).trigger('click');` if you want to click automatically

Comment: @John Ok, I'll use .trigger('click') - Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $(document).on('click', '.classname', function(){
            var self = $(this);
            var  total_items = $('.classname').length; // 10
            var index = self.index(); //2 for 3rd element
            if (index < total_items) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.classname').eq(index+1).trigger('click');
                }, 3000);
            }    
        });
```

this will call the next clicks in 3 sec interval

i don't know why you are using a randomizer function.you can allow the user to make that click

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps you - can't see your markup, but it should get you on the right track. I've also changed your `.click()` to a `.trigger('click')` which should be quite a bit more dependable.

#### JavaScript

```
function pickrandom() {
    var elems = $(".classname");
    if (elems.length) {
        var curTarget = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
        console.log(curTarget);
        $(elems[curTarget]).trigger('click');

        // Find index of our next target - if we've reached
        // the end, go back to beginning
        var nextTarget = curTarget + 1;
        if( nextTarget > elems.length ) {
            nextTarget = 0;
        }

        // Wait 3 seconds and click the next div
        setTimeout( function() { $(elems[nextTarget]).trigger('click'); }, 3000 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(el.text());
    el.toggleClass("click");
  }, 2000);
});

var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * $("div").length) + 1);
var index = random - 1;
console.log("Random number: ", random);

var clicker = setInterval(function() {
  if (index === $("div").length) {
    clearInterval(clicker);
    console.log("cleared interval");
  } else {
    $("div").eq(index).click();
    index++;
  }
}, 2000)
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.click {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Div 1
</div>
<div>
  Div 2
</div>
<div>
  Div 3
</div>
<div>
  Div 4
</div>
<div>
  Div 5
</div>
<div>
  Div 6
</div>
```